# Null coalesce operator with casting

Tags: php, php-7, null-coalescing-operator

I have upgraded to PHP 7 and started using the null coalesce operator to convert things like

```
$email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '';
```

to

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'] ?? '';
```

but I can't figure out how to do this if I am casting as well. For example, the for the old statement

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

I would think something like

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'] ?? 0;
```

should work, but it doesn't appear to in the sense that, if `$_GET['id']` is not set, `$id` resolves to `0` but I get the Notice

> Notice: Undefined index: id in test.php on line 2

Comment: Associativity is your problem: `$id = (int) ($GET['id'] ?? 0);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `(int)` cast gets precedence over the `??` operator, so use brackets:

```
$id = (int) ($_GET['id'] ?? 0);
```

Comment: If one didn't want to simply think about the order of operations, one could think about it in terms of "it's the result of the whole expression - whichever side gets used - I want to be an int, not simply one operand or the other". It's the same thing, but just frames it in a more "real world" sort of way, perhaps.